# Find out a button's color and set its color to default

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way to find out a QPushButton's color? I need to find it out, check if it's green and then to set it to default windows color (light blue), as it was at the very begining. 
  Any way to do that?

Comment: It depends on how green color was set. It can be done using `QPalette`, using QSS or painted inside `paintEvent`.

Comment: @hank It was set as 
`QColor green=Qt::green;`
`QString green_col=green.name();`
`setStyleSheet("background-color: " + green_col)`

Comment: Then you can get current button style sheet using `QWidget::styleSheet` and parse it to detect if the button is green.